# Trigonometric double angle formulas problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to simplify the answer to an equation I had to compute, namely, simplifying $\sin^2 (2y) + \cos^2 (2y)$. I know that $\sin^2 (y) + \cos^2 (y) = 1$ but is there anything like that I can use at all?

Comment: Well, put $x=2y$... and you will see that this is the same....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general $$\sin^2(\color{red}{\rm something}) + \cos^2(\color{red}{\text{the same thing}})=1.$$So your expression is just $1$.

Comment: Well, if I say something is the Eiffel Tower? :)

Comment: something must be a real number

Comment: If $\text{Eiffel Tower} \in \Bbb C$ we're good.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly hope that you know, sine and cosine are functions and aren't being multiplied by angles.

$$\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}=1$$

where, $x \in \mathbb R$ and so therefore, $2x \in \mathbb R$

**For instance:**

$$\cos^2{30^o}+\sin^2{30^o}=\cos^2{60^o}+\sin^2{60^o}$$
$$1=1$$